# Illegal type conversion from std.STANDARD.BIT_VECTOR to ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (array element type difference)

Tags: vhdl

```vhdl
library ieee;                                -- line 1
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;                 -- line 2
                                             -- line 3
entity find_errors is port(                      -- line 4
    a: in bit_vector(0 to 3);                   -- line 5
    b: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);         -- line 6
    c: in bit_vector(5 downto 0)) ;           -- line 7
end find_errors;                             -- line 8
                                             -- line 9
architecture not_good of find_errors  is       -- line 10
  begin                                      -- line 11
  my_label: process  (c)                        -- line 12
    begin                                    -- line 13
    if c = "001111" then -- c is equal to 001111 -- line 14
      b <= std_logic_vector(a);               -- line 15
    else                                     -- line 16
     b <= "0101";                            -- line 17
    end if  ;                                 -- line 18
  end process;                               -- line 19
end not_good ;                                -- line 20
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: b is a std_logic_vector, a is a bit_vector. They cannot be directly type converted as they are not similar types. You need to use the `to_bitvector` type conversion function.

Comment: Or to_stdlogicvector in this case. Also, be very clear on how copying between vectors with opposite range directions actually works ... and test it to make sure.